# Is there a difference between the keyword 'typeof' in Javascript and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have this example.

```
const Bob = 'Bobby';

interface IName {
    text: typeof Bob;
}

let newName: IName = {
    text: 'Bobby'
}
```

Where I initialize the variable 'newName', if I try to change the text 'Bobby' to something else, it gives me an error, yet the new text is still a string type.

If I do `console.log(typeof Bob)` it prints 'string', so in the interface the key 'text' should be of type 'string' too right?

Then why does typescript limit my options to just the text 'Bobby' when setting the value of 'text' in 'newName'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Bob` is `const`, TypeScript knows that it will always have the value `'Bobby'`, so it refines the type from `string` to just the [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `'Bobby'`. This then propagates though the interface to your `newName` instance. If you have an editor with TS support you can hover over `IName.text` and see:

```
(property) IName.text: "Bobby"
```

JS knows nothing about the type annotations, so you get the runtime type which is still `string`.

Comment: Also, worth clarifying that there *are* two `typeof` operators. One is the [JavaScript one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) which gives the base type of a variable according to JS, the other is TS's `typeof` that only exists as part of the type system and is used to interrogate it and produce more dynamic typing.

Comment: @VLAZ: True in the case where the `typeof` is part of a type annotation. In regular code it should be identical, i think.

Comment: Yes, there is only one `typeof` at runtime. It is slightly overloaded by TS to act as [a typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) but it's just a slight enhancement over what it already does. The interaction with the type system is fairly minimal, since it only does type narrowing for few very narrow things - primitives and objects/functions. The `typeof` from TypeScript is a different operator altogether. IMO should have been named differently but I think that might have lead to more confusion.